Why did SpaceX Starship ITF5 float so low in the water after splash landing?
An empty Starship is lower density than an empty Budweiser can. The camera shot of it floating post-splashdown looked like it was floating vertically upside down which is not consistent with empty tanks.
I was confused by the video feed after splashdown. One view seemed to be underwater, looking forward from the aft fin, then another view seemed to show an explosion. Is there a reliable interpretation of the video which would explain ruptured tanks and the ship floating low in the water?


That actually looks more like the engines down in the water (The densest part) and the upper tank blown off and you can see the downcomer and the landing tank hanging off to the right.  So would make sense to float, engines down.

@geoffc ... that would make more sense.

Starship landed engines down and after the explosion the rear of starship was still pointing engines down. As the engines and thrust structure are relatively heavy this makes sense. If you check the footage filmed from the landing bouy you can even see the remains of the downcomer pipe sticking up out of the remains of the tank.
